# npx eslint --fix error when adding plugins to vite.config.ts

Tags: typescript, eslint, vite

For some reason I'm getting this error when adding plugins to the vite.config.ts file :

`1:1  error  Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'`

vite.config.ts :

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react(), eslint()],
});
```

If I leave only the react plugin it works fine, but whatever extra component I add will cause this issue, this is my eslintrc file :

.eslintrc.json :

```
{
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:node/recommended", "prettier"],
    "plugins": ["node", "prettier"],
    "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": "error",
        "block-scoped-var": "error",
        "eqeqeq": "error",
        "no-var": "error",
        "prefer-const": "error",
        "eol-last": "error",
        "prefer-arrow-callback": "error",
        "no-trailing-spaces": "error",
        "quotes": ["warn", "single", {"avoidEscape": true}],
        "no-restricted-properties": [
            "error",
            {
                "object": "describe",
                "property": "only"
            },
            {
                "object": "it",
                "property": "only"
            }
        ]
    },
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
            "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
            "extends": ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],
            "rules": {
                "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
                "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "off",
                "@typescript-eslint/no-warning-comments": "off",
                "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
                "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "off",
                "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
                "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
                "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": "off",
                "@typescript-eslint/camelcase": "off",
                "node/no-missing-import": "off",
                "node/no-empty-function": "off",
                "node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax": "off",
                "node/no-missing-require": "off",
                "node/shebang": "off",
                "no-dupe-class-members": "off",
                "require-atomic-updates": "off"
            },
            "parserOptions": {
                "ecmaVersion": 2018,
                "sourceType": "module"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm also using typescript 5.0.3, don't know if it's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your `tsconfig.json` file includes `vitest.config.ts`:

```json
{
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "vitest.config.ts"]
}
```

Then ensure your `.eslintrc.json` file includes `vitest.config.ts`:

```json
"overrides": [
  {
    "files": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "vitest.config.ts"],
  }
]
```

Alternatively, edit `.eslintrc.json` to configure the default parser (instead of the `overrides` parser):

```json
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "2018",
    "project": "./tsconfig.json",
    "sourceType": "module"
}
```

If that still doesn't work then try adding this:

```json
{
  "ignorePatterns": ["!vitest.config.ts"]
}
```

You need to add it as a top-level key in the config.

You don't say how you're generating the error. If it's command line then you can ignore this next remark. But if it's directly within VSCode then do *Developer: Reload Window* after the change to ensure it's applied.

Comment: Still getting that error

Comment: @JoãoPedro I added a suggestion to the end of my answer, give that a try.